# Div Container Not Responding to CSS Code / Commands

Tags: html, css

On a practice website, I presently have a div container with the class "jumbo-slider__information" that's not responding to any CSS code.  I'm trying to add a blue border-box and also manipulate the positioning of the child elements through CSS using:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

I've double-checked the class name for any misspellings.

Please view my brief 2-minute screen share video here describing the problem in detail:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nY6Gbw2UBhAgUZDZA4yUiW3nd9dkJ9Hm/view

Also please view my complete HTML and CSS code here on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/rashadnelson/pen/ExXZRZV

I look forward to any insights.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is invalid right above the `.jumbo-slider__information` selector. Remove the semicolon after `}`:

```css
.jumbo-slider__slide--active .jumbo-slider__slide-bg {
  opacity: 0.5;
};
```

This should be:

```css
.jumbo-slider__slide--active .jumbo-slider__slide-bg {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[CSS Syntax Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax)

Comment: Wow :-), simply awesome.  Something so simple, yet it took another set of fresh eyes to identify the culprit.  I can't thank you enough @Jake Worth.  Any recommended tools you use to search for such errors or did you catch it by the naked eye?